Local Frame on an Almost Complex Manifold
Let $(M, J)$ be an almost complex manifold of dimension $2n$. For each point $p \in M$, I know that we can find linearly independent tangent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in T_pM$ such that
$$
v_1, \ldots, v_n, J_p v_1, \ldots, J_p v_n
$$
form a basis for $T_pM$. My question is, can we construct a basis of this type that varies smoothly as a function of $p$?
Motivation: I would like to show that on an almost complex manifold, we can find a local frame for the real tangent bundle $TM$ of the form
$$
X_1, \ldots, X_n, JX_1, \ldots, JX_n,
$$
where $J$ is the almost complex structure. I can see how to do this at the level of each tangent space $T_pM$, but I am struggling with ensuring that the resulting vector fields $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are smooth (or even continuous) across a neighborhood of $p$.
I am looking for guidance on how to proceed with this or whether there are conditions under which we can guarantee the existence of such smooth local frames.
Additionally, if anyone knows of a good reference for this type of construction in almost complex geometry, I would greatly appreciate it.

Are you aware that $(TM, J)$ is a complex vector bundle?

@MichaelAlbanese Yes

Then you know that there is a local trivialisation of this complex vector bundle. Can you see why this leads to a basis of the type you're looking for?

@MichaelAlbanese let me see first

@MichaelAlbanese Ah yes thankyou

The following works: Assume $X_1, JX_1, \dots, X_k, JX_k$ are pointwise linearly independent but do not span the tangent space. Let $X_{k+1}$ be any vector field that is not in the pointwise span of $X_1, JX_1, \dots, X_k, JX_k$. Then $X_1, JX_1, \dots, X_k, JX_k, X_{k+1}, JX_{k+1}$ are pointwise linearly independent.

@Deane Why don’t you write it as a full answer. I’ll happily accept it.

@Uncool, I have a countersuggestion. I didn't prove the last sentence. Any chance you want to write the full answer yourself and accept it as the correct one?
